# What is the time signature of Symphony No. 9 (Beethoven)?

Tags: time-signatures

I found this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._9_(Beethoven)):

[image]

(in the *IV. Finale* section)

`1` has four crotchets;
`2` has two crotchets and one minim
`3` has one and a half crotchets, one quaver, and one minim

The total duration of each bar is different from each other. So what is the time signature? Shouldn't they be all equal?

Comment: All of those are in fact identical in length and match  4/4 time  signature. Note, that the time signature may be different for each movement.

Comment: "The total duration of each bar is different from each other. " - what do you understand to be the duration of a minim, and a quaver?

Comment: I think to best answer your question, it would help if you explain how you’re calculating that the durations of the bars are different. That’s because there’s an error in your calculations. The duration of each bar is in fact the same. So the answer to your question a correction to how you’re adding up those durations. Before we can offer a correction, we have to see how you’re adding it up to find your mistake(s).

Comment: The total duration of each bar is **not** different. One minim is equivalent to two crotchets, a dotted crotchet and a quaver together are also equivalent to two crotchets. Do the maths and you will see that these all add up to the equivalent of 4 crotchets.

Comment: What is the point of a music theory Q&A forum that closes questions about how to do music theory? Do we really need more upvoting of guitar gear questions?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I'm with you. Perhaps the question deserves to be closed as unclear, because it does not explain how the asker reached the conclusion that the music is inconsistent with the time signature, but the question "help me understand why this music doesn't match its time signature" should be on topic.  If we closed every theory question where the asker has misunderstood the underlying theory we would have precious few theory questions.  Further, this question _is_ "substantial" and _does_ "refer to a well-defined work ... including a concrete reference (sheet music, etc.)."

Comment: I would vote to re-open if OP told us *how* he came to the conclusion that each bar was different in length. Even though it does seem like a schoolboy error, with little or no research.

Comment: "...a schoolboy error, with little or no research"  ...isn't that the basis for nearly all guitarist questions about modes of a diatonic scale and pentatonic boxes?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis - sad, but true...   With close to 25K questions, maybe it's time to tighten the criteria a little?

Comment: I would vote to close, as this question is asked using false premises.

Answer (score 6):

Your question isn't really "what is the time signature" but how to add up the durations of note rhythm values.

The time signature of the example is `4/4` and so there will be 4 quarter notes per measure.

For this passage the simplest thing to do is count up duration using the smallest unit of rhythm value which in this case is an eighth note.

```
BASIC NOTE VALUES

1 eighth note (quaver)    = 1 eighth note
1 quarter note (crotchet) = 2 eighth notes
1 dotted quarter note     = 3 eighth notes
1 half note (minim)       = 4 eighth notes

VALUES AND DURATION OF EACH MEASURE

m.1
1 quarter note        = 2 eighth notes
1 quarter note        = 2 eighth notes
1 quarter note        = 2 eighth notes
1 quarter note        = 2 eighth notes
--------------------------------------
total                   8 eighth notes

m.2 
1 half note           = 4 eighth notes
1 quarter note        = 2 eighth notes
1 quarter note        = 2 eighth notes
--------------------------------------
total                   8 eighth notes

m.3
1 dotted quarter note = 3 eighth notes
1 eighth note         = 1 eighth note
1 half note           = 4 eighth notes
--------------------------------------
total                   8 eighth notes
```

You could also add up durations using `quarter note = 1`, but then you would need to use values like `dotted quarter = 1.5` and `eighth = 0.5` and that seems a bit more difficult than adding whole numbers.

Comment: I like this approach because it looks like you've identified the problem OP was having.  But the result would be so much nicer with a quarter note as your base unit.

Answer (score 3):

With a time signature of, say, 4/4, it does not mean every bar must have 4 crotchets (1/4 notes). How could it? It would be a very boring piece rhythm-wise!

Each of those bars posted actually has the **equivalent** of 4 crotchets, and that's what counts - literally. The time signature tells *how many* of *what*, admittedly. But there are many combinations of notes which can be, and are, used to fill each bar - including rests. And once a time signature is stated, the writer is duty bound to keep to it, or change to a different time signature if the last one is inappropriate, which happens, although not that often in 'Classical' music, at least

So, this question is actually asked using false premises, but hopefully this answer will explain why.

EDIT: I guess you're considering the 4th movement, which has a time signature of 'C'. That in fact, is another way to designate 4/4, which may be where the confusion comes from?

Comment: Personally, I don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: @Pyromonk - which part don't you quite understand? This is ripe for vtc, but I'm trying to explain what's wrong with the reasoning behind the question.

Comment: True but irrelevant, since the time signature could be 2/2 as well.  TheRealAnswer(TM) is "go look up the score, dude"  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - why irrelevant? It's actually a fact. How can that fact be irrelevant when referring to time signatures? And the answer to most questions here could easily be 'Go look it up, dude.' Hardly sensible answers, though...

Comment: @Tim  the OP was incorrect in his attempt to observe note-lengths, but is **question** was "what is the time signature," which I see you edited in but buried the lede.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - 'buried the lede'? Not in my vocabulary - or dictionary, for that matter. Yes, I answered the OP's question - eventually.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lede. I keep forgetting that that's the proper spelling, not "lead"! See [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lede) as well—an intentional spelling mutation.

Comment: @AndyBonner - of course. And I used to play lead guitar; it was very, very heavy... And no, it wasn't heavy metal - or was it..?

Comment: @AndyBonner "lede" is journalistic jargon spelling, not "proper" spelling.  The word is the same word that denotes the second tenor in a barbershop quartet.  The jargon spelling is primarily a convenience to avoid ambiguity with the noun _lead._  M-W seems to have a use of "lede" from 1947, but [it's only taken off in the last decade or two, and the traditional spelling remains the more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bury+the+lead%2Cbury+the+lede&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Tim  It's from the world of newspapers, easily googled

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - thanks. I read newspapers- occasionally - they're too depressing - but haven't come across that particular, perhaps esoteric word. But 'lead' would have sufficed, wouldn't it? Maybe not so prevalent in UK papers.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, we can say it's in either 4/4 or 2/2 time, sometimes marked as  (common time) or  (cut time) respectively.    (There are other esoteric possibilities, but let's keep it simple).  If we look at the actual score, we can see that Beethoven chose .

[image]

You say "The total duration of each bar is different from each other."  You are mistaken.  Minims are worth two crotchets, a dotted crotchet is one-and-a-half, a quaver is a half.   So each bar adds up to four crotchets.

Think of it like (British) money.   4p can be 4x1p, 2x2p, 1p+1p+1½p+½p, or a 4p piece (OK, I know we don't have ½p coins any more, or a 4p piece, but you get the idea!)

Comment: +1 for answering the title question, but -1 for finding the wrong time signature.  The first appearance of the _Ode to Joy_ theme is marked _Allegro Assai,_ half note = 80, with a time signature of `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all measures have the same length. The notes use the time differently in every measure, but they add all up to 4/4.